IIS redirect folders and files in one folder to new folder
I've searched for a while on this and haven't found a solution.
I have a documents folder and I want to redirect all of the folders and files within documents from /documents to /images/documents. This is one of the rules I have tried and nothing I try seems to work. Other rules I have that are simpler work fine.
Example, I want domain.com/documents/news/2024/file.pdf
to redirect to domain.com/images/documents/news/2024/file.pdf
this is where I am
<rule name="..." stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^documents/news/(.*)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="images/documents/news/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>


https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 You should use type of Redirect.

You can try this rule, If this doesn't work, please let me know
 <rewrite>
   <rules>
     <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^documents/(.*)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="/images/documents/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
     </rule>
   </rules>
 </rewrite>
 

